# Does JavaScript keep a log of a single variables different states?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a quiz and, on completion, I would like to display all of the user's answers without creating different variables to store each one.

e.g.,

```
var state1 = {
    name: 'Delaware',
    capital: 'Dover',
    orderOfEntry: 1,
};

var userAnswer.quiz = prompt('What is the state capital of ' + state1.name +'?');

var state2 = {
    name: 'Pennsylvania',
    capital: 'Harrisburg',
    orderOfEntry: 2,
};

var userAnswer.quiz = prompt('What is the state capital of ' + state2.name +'?');
```

Instead of creating a new variable for each answer, I would just like to access the answers in the order they are given, like an array index.

Comment: You could just use an Array and use .push() to add items to it. Then, you could access them in the order they were added using the index.

Comment: Don't want to be mean, but: 1) Your question is poorly written and formatted. 2) You have to say what you have tried, as I see you have an idea about arrays and how to use them. 3) StackOverflow was a community for enthusiasts, but now every simple question that can be answered by simply searching for it on Google is being asked. SO is not really "noob friendly", this is not the place to ask for tutorials or basic language syntax.

Comment: `"access the answers in the order they are given, like an array index"` - Didn't you just answer your own question?  Use an array?

Comment: Yeah, I'm just starting, You're not being mean, Im just now learning how to use all this stuff.  Thanks for the help guys, I've started figuring it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can store anything in an Array:

```
var answers = [{
    name: 'Delaware',
    capital: 'Dover'
}, {
    name: 'Pennsylvania',
    capital: 'Harrisburg'
}];
var i;

for (i = 0; i < answers.length; i++) {
    answers[i].answer = prompt('What is the state capital of ' + answers[i].name + '?');
}
```

Now each Object in `answers` will have an `answer` property that contains the user-supplied value from each `prompt`.